# php/python date conversion

Tags: php, python

Guys, I have a python script which builds up a MySQL table with timestamps that look like:

```
2011-04-18 09:54:45
```

To interface with this MySQL table, I need a php script to match updates.  If I run this in PHP:

```
$todaysdate = date(DATE_RFC822);
print $todaysdate;
```

returns:

```
Mon, 18 Apr 11 09:57:57 -0400
```

How do I get php to return  2011-04-18 09:54:45 style result? instead of a RFC822?

Thanks!

Comment: Suggested code:
http://pastebin.com/KWRMXv1J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using date like this should do the trick

```
$todaysdate = date("Y-m-j H:i:s");
print $todaysdate;
```

Here is a list of the options you can use.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: `G` is the hour without leading zeros. i think `H` would be better in this case (and, in fact, the hour with leading zeros is what Clustermagnet is looking for as we can see in his example).

Answer (score 1):

just ask the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
$todaysdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Guys, I hope this is an OK way to retrieve today's results from datetime mysql field...
<p>
    $todaysdate = date("Y-m-d");
</p>
    if ($result = mysql_query("SELECT url,date,successful_urls FROM collection_growth WHERE date > '$todaysdate'",$con))
      {
       blah
      }